# Como otorgar permiso a grupo de usuarios para editar y eliminar

Tags: laravel

Tengo una política donde actualmente se revisa si el usuario es el creador del registro o no y si es así se le permite continuar en la edición o eliminación del registro.

En la política tengo esta función para eso:

```
public function pass(User $user, DatosModel $datousuario)
    {
            return $user->id == $datousuario->idusuario;
    }
```

Por otra parte el registro tiene un campo que se llama idgrupo que por ejemplo puede ser el '10' y quisiera entregar permiso también a otros usuarios que perteneces a ese grupo '10' para editar y eliminar registros.

¿Cúal es la manera para realizar esto?

Comment: puedes usar en tu controlador `$this->authorize('pass', Tu_Modelo);`

Comment: o en tu vista con la directiva `@can` y te recomiendo que uses `===` en vez de `==`

Answer (score 1):

Finalmente agregue a la política en los métodos de edición y eliminación lo siguiente y esto le permite editar al creador del registro y a los pertenecientes al grupo del registro:

```
if($user->id == $datousuario->idusuario){
            return true;
        }else{  $idgrupos=User::findOrFail(Auth()->user()->id)->grupospertenece
                                ->pluck('id')->toArray();
                if (array_search($datousuario->idgrupo, $idgrupos)) {
                    return true;
                }else{
                return false;
                }
        }
```